# Error: "network_interface": conflicts with vpc_security_group_ids

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create an aws instance with an aws_network_interface as below:

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "lustre-mds01" {
  subnet_id   = "${var.subnet_id}"
  private_ips = ["10.1.0.10"] 
}

resource "aws_instance" "lustre-mds01" {
  ami                    = "${var.ec2_ami}"
  instance_type          = "t2.nano"
  key_name               = "${var.key_name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [ "${var.vpc_security_group_id}" ]

  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = 128
  }

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = "${aws_network_interface.lustre-mds01.id}"
    device_index         = 0
  }
}
```

However, this results in:

> Error: "network_interface": conflicts with vpc_security_group_ids

It appears there is an issue for this, but the ticket was closed due to inactivity.  I'm a terraform noob, so I'm not sure if this looks like a bug or is just user error.

My environment:

```
$ terraform -v
Terraform v0.12.2
+ provider.aws v2.15.0
+ provider.external v1.1.2
+ provider.local v1.2.2
+ provider.null v2.1.2
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`aws_network_interface` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/network_interface.html) allows you to set the security group for the interface (security groups are scoped by the ENI so this makes sense) so if you define the `network_interface` block then you're overriding the default ENI and so can't specify security groups at the instance level.

So in your case you probably want something like:

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "lustre-mds01" {
  subnet_id       = "${var.subnet_id}"
  private_ips     = ["10.1.0.10"]
  security_groups = ["${var.vpc_security_group_id}"] 
}

resource "aws_instance" "lustre-mds01" {
  ami           = "${var.ec2_ami}"
  instance_type = "t2.nano"
  key_name      = "${var.key_name}"

  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = 128
  }

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = "${aws_network_interface.lustre-mds01.id}"
    device_index         = 0
  }
}
```

However, I would question *why* you are replacing the default ENI here when it's much simpler to just set the private IP address of the instance directly in the [`aws_instance` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.htm) instead:

```
resource "aws_instance" "lustre-mds01" {
  ami                    = "${var.ec2_ami}"
  instance_type          = "t2.nano"
  key_name               = "${var.key_name}"
  subnet_id              = "${var.subnet_id}"
  private_ip             = "10.1.0.10"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.vpc_security_group_id}"]

  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = 128
  }
}
```

You would also probably benefit from using data sources to select your [security group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/security_group.html) and [AMI](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html) instead of passing in opaque IDs for these. This allows them to be more self documenting.